# Use terraform to create a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

In the below example we can see the code for a lambda function which creates an alarm in cloudwatch based on cpu utilization.

```
import boto3
import collections
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

    alarm = client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='CPU Alarm',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    Statistic='Average',
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold',
    Threshold=70.0,
    Period=10,
    EvaluationPeriods=1,
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': '{instance_id}'
        }
    ],
    Unit='Percent',
    ActionsEnabled=True,
    AlarmActions=['arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:CloudWatch'])
```

I am struggling to understand how I can get this to create in terraform. Can anyone help please? The key thing is I need it to work so that as soon as an instance starts up, the alarm gets created, the that is the event to trigger the lambda.

I "Think" that my .tf file would look something like this...?

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "CPU Alarm" {
  alarm_name                = "CPU Alarm"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "1"
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
  period                    = "10"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "70"
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

I am keen to have it working so every instance that gets started up gets a specific metric created that monitors its CPU. Has anyone done this before and able to assist please...

Thanks.

Comment: So this alarm that you create in TF, is supposed to trigger a lambda function that you have in question?

Comment: Lambda function would be created in tf and the lambda would be trigggered by a 'running' status' in an EC2. The lambda function creates the cpu alarm.

Comment: Are you managing your EC2 instances for which you want to create the alarms with Terraform as well? If yes couldn't you combine your `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` with a `for_each` to create the required alarms?

Comment: I agree with what yvesonline said.  If the EC2 instances is being created by Terraform, it should be possible to have Terraform create the CW alert as well.

If the EC2 instance is being created some other way, and you really do need a Lambda to configure the CW alerts, then I suggest looking into EC2 State Change events that can triigger Lambda's.  It's under AWS EventBridge in the latest documentation.  That would allows you to trigger your function (with the instance ID and state) when the instance is launched.

Answer (score 0):

There are few elements that you would have to create and interconnect with each other to accomplish your aim.

1. Create [aws_cloudwatch_event_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule) to capture instances going into running state. The following rule can be used:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["running"]
  }
}
```

2. Setup [aws_lambda_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission) so that the rule can **trigger** your lambda.
3. Setup your lambda function as the target for the rule using [aws_cloudwatch_event_target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target).
4. Your function, when triggered would **create the alarm** for the instance.

Depending on your specific use-case, the rule would also be triggered if instances go from stopped to running states. Your **lambda should account** for this and check if there is an existing alarm for an instance.

Other possibility is to capture API call `create-instance` using CloudTrial trials and then setup the alarm.

Comment: The answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I've attempted some further research triggered by the links you've given but actually this response has not helped. L

Comment: CW Events is definitely useful if you want a Lambda to run when an instance it launched.